# Rotate HTML 5 video without also rotating controls?

Tags: html, css, rotation, html5-video

Using the CSS transform() property (and the -moz-, -webkit-, etc verisons), it's easy to rotate an HTML 5 video:

```
video {
   transform:rotate(90deg);
}
```

However, this rotates the controls along with the video. Is there any way to keep the video itself rotated without also rotating the controls?

Comment: Are you writing the player yourself, or using a plugin?

Comment: Writing the player myself.

Comment: Cool. Can you post some code showing what you've got?

Comment: It's the bare minimum:
`<video src="movie.mp4" controls></video>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I see, you're using the native video controls. What you'll need to do is build custom controls if you want to style them separately. Here's a good tutorial on how to do that http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/building-custom-controls-for-html5-videos. Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

Ok, For next rotate control.
Add this in Css:

```
video::-webkit-media-controls {
 transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -webkit-transform:scale(-1, 1); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(-1, 1); /* Firefox */
}
video::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure {
 transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -webkit-transform:scale(-1, 1); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(-1, 1); /* Firefox */
}
```