# How do I change the orientation of a <video> without changing the orientation of the video controls

Tags: html, css, video

```html
<video controls>
</video>
```

```css
video {
 transform: scaleX(-1)
}
```

This mirrors the video at 180 degrees but it mirrors the controls as well.

I have tried transforming the wrapper element for the video element with `.wrapper {transform: scaleX(-1)` as well and still no change.

Building controls from scratch is honestly out of my skill atm so I'm hoping to do this with just css like `transform: scaleX()`.

How do I maintain mirror only the video whilst maintaining the controls in their original orientation?

MIRRORED IMAGE
[image: Unmirrored image]

UNMIRRORED IMAGE
[image: Mirrored Image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rotate HTML 5 video without also rotating controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22927466/rotate-html-5-video-without-also-rotating-controls)

Comment: Alas, it doesn't (the second solution anyway). Building the controls in the first solution is beyond my skill right now and i was hoping to get a solution which used css properties like `transform: scale()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I can think is to hide the default controls, invert the video, and create your own controls. I've made a simple example below that you can customize as you'd like.

```js
const video = document.getElementById('videoPlayer');
const playPauseButton = document.getElementById('playPause');
const muteToggleButton = document.getElementById('muteToggle');
const fullscreenToggleButton = document.getElementById('fullscreenToggle');
const progressBarContainer = document.getElementById('progressBarContainer');
const progressBarFilled = document.getElementById('progressBarFilled');
const timeDisplay = document.getElementById('timeDisplay');

function togglePlayPause() {
  if (video.paused) {
    video.play();
    playPauseButton.textContent = 'Pause';
  } else {
    video.pause();
    playPauseButton.textContent = 'Play';
  }
}

function toggleMute() {
  video.muted = !video.muted;
  muteToggleButton.textContent = video.muted ? 'Unmute' : 'Mute';
}

function toggleFullscreen() {
  if (!document.fullscreenElement) {
    video.requestFullscreen();
  } else {
    document.exitFullscreen();
  }
}

function updateProgressBar() {
  const percentage = (video.currentTime / video.duration) * 100;
  progressBarFilled.style.width = percentage + '%';
  updateTimerDisplay();
}

function seek(e) {
  const newTime = (e.offsetX / progressBarContainer.offsetWidth) * video.duration;
  video.currentTime = newTime;
}

function updateTimerDisplay() {
  const formattedCurrentTime = new Date(video.currentTime * 1000).toISOString().substr(14, 5);
  const formattedDuration = new Date(video.duration * 1000).toISOString().substr(14, 5);
  timeDisplay.textContent = `${formattedCurrentTime} / ${formattedDuration}`;
}

playPauseButton.addEventListener('click', togglePlayPause);
muteToggleButton.addEventListener('click', toggleMute);
fullscreenToggleButton.addEventListener('click', toggleFullscreen);
progressBarContainer.addEventListener('click', seek);
video.addEventListener('timeupdate', updateProgressBar);
```

```css
.video-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 640px;
}

.video-container video {
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.video-controls {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px -5px 5px 5px;
}

.video-controls button {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.progress-bar-container {
  flex-grow: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.progress-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: #666;
  position: relative;
}

.progress-bar-filled {
  background: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
}

.time {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-container">
  <video id="videoPlayer">
    <source src="https://uce23327b0bab5175c1c0c0cbc0a.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/cd/0/inline/CJhjJhXufoSbuAopjZ-4fWNFBDaEyp-tZ_08YeqLy-avay9VQ4coVwwdsfHZWhB9S7W6oOzxpx-e2R6Mj5Fa1QzbkumZOHOlNhHpud84YbApN3-tZHbuLrCQgakMIQ6YQRlu6I2GrK_UwdAqmaEdELw6/file#" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
  <div class="video-controls">
    <button id="playPause">Play/Pause</button>
    <button id="muteToggle">Mute/Unmute</button>
    <button id="fullscreenToggle">Fullscreen</button>
    <div class="progress-bar-container" id="progressBarContainer">
      <div class="progress-bar">
        <div class="progress-bar-filled" id="progressBarFilled"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="time" id="timeDisplay">00:00 / 00:00</div>
  </div>
</div>
```